# grunt live reload error

Tags: gruntjs, livereload, grunt-express

Sorry I am new to grunt and trying to build a system where I can have a live reload with sass. Sass everything was easy to set up and compile but the livereload I am stuck, I followed this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SL6uYHsl2Ic

and when I ran the command grunt server received an error saying
Path must be a string. This is my basic build system. Thanks!

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
  sass: {                              // Task
    dist: {                            // Target
      options: {                       // Target options
        style: 'expanded'
      },
      files: {                         // Dictionary of files
        'css/main.css': 'sass/main.scss'       // 'destination': 'source'
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    options: {livereload:true},
    css: {
      files: ['sass/**/*.scss'],
      tasks: ['sass'],
    },
  },
  express:{
    all:{
        options:{
            port:9000,
            hostname:'localhost',
            base:'.',
            livereload:true,
        }
    }
  } 
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-express-server');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass'])
grunt.registerTask('server', ['express', 'watch']);
```

};

Comment: If I well understood, you want to restart your express when your saas are compiled?

Comment: No i just cant get the express to run with the live reload when i enter the command grunt server. It shows an error that it must be in a string. I followed what that guy did the video tutorial. Thanks

Comment: try removing the "all" object from "express" (worked for me):

  express:{
        options:{
            port:9000,
            hostname:'localhost',
            base:'.',
            livereload:true,
        }
  }

Comment: @YonatanAyalon thanks it removed the error but my livereload is not working still when I type in http://localhost:9000/